# How to setup GA with multiple accounts and reports

Tags: google-analytics

Hey Guys, i need some help about with a setup of GA in one site.
This site have information from 2 account, 1 for consolidated and another for country. Yesterday I tried to add another ID (third ID) for TI purposes but when I a looked the stats in GA have been lost.

This is the code, it's correct?

```
    
    var pageTrackerCons = _gat._getTracker("UA-5352676-2");
    pageTrackerCons._setDomainName("none");
    pageTrackerCons._setAllowLinker(true);
    pageTrackerCons._setCustomVar(1,"Login","No",2);
    pageTrackerCons._trackPageview();
    var pageTrackerPais = _gat._getTracker("UA-5358924-2");
    pageTrackerPais._setDomainName("none");
    pageTrackerPais._setAllowLinker(true);
    pageTrackerPais._setCustomVar(1,"Login","No",2);
    pageTrackerPais._trackPageview();
    var pageTrackerServ1 = _gat._getTracker("UA-22944815-2");
    pageTrackerServ1._setDomainName("none");
    pageTrackerServ1._setAllowLinker(true);
    pageTrackerServ1._trackPageview();
```

UA-22944815-2 es de the new ID with the problems, stats for anothers accounts are fine.

Can we use 3 diferents ID in one site? How?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's totally possible to use 3 trackers on one page and send data to 3 accounts.

Your code looks correct, maybe it's just a delay in reporting. It may happen that data only shows up after a day or two.

You should first confirm that you have 3 GIF requests to the google-analytics.com servers, each which that utmac parameter matching the accounts that you are expecting.

If you have a GIF request with utmac=UA-22944815-2 , then it means data is collected for your new account. Make sure you look at the right profile, and that the profile has no filters.